# There are the normalized values of the davies_bouldin_score coefficient in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn

Is this measure normalized between 0 and 1?

At https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.davies_bouldin_score.html I understand that it is not normalized but is this in scikit-learn? Or generally?

Answer (score 0):

**The minimum value is `0` but the maximum can be above `1`.**

From the documentation:

> This index signifies the average ‘similarity’ between clusters, where
>   the similarity is a measure that compares the distance between
>   clusters with the size of the clusters themselves.
>
> **Zero is the lowest possible score. Values closer to zero indicate a better partition.**

---

**Example where the score is > 1:**

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import davies_bouldin_score

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=13, random_state=1).fit(X)
labels = kmeans.labels_

davies_bouldin_score(X, labels)

1.068885319440245
```